# Pycharm commits to github not shown in my github history

Tags: github, pycharm

When using username/password combo to commit to my Github account via Pycharm, I don't get green squares (badges) in my Github commit history. Commits are made to my own public repository

This is not that big technological issue but there are people who judge others based on number of those green squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the email address that you use in your commits matches the email address of your github account. To change the email address, use `git config user.email` (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/) for more information).

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I even got my previous commits recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I ran commands through the terminal in PyCharm commits and push requests were not seen in the git hub site.
I then used the following command in pycharm and it did work.
Git -> GitHub-> Create Pull Request
-> In the window that opens click on the create pull request
See image for more information

[Screenshot from pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePjvU.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).